# Change Accurev Workspace Owner

Tags: accurev

I'm trying to transfer a workspace to another user.

Is there a way to change the owner of a workspace in accurev?

Answer (score 0):

The Manual Way

As User1:

The first `mkws` command was done at some point in the past to initially create the workspace. The `chws' command is just taking the workspace and dumping it to an arbitrary place.

```
accurev login User1 User1Password
accurev mkws -w wkspace_name -b backing_stream -l /wkspaces/wkspace_original_location
accurev chws -w wkspace_name -l /wkspaces/temp_location_one
```

As User2:

```
accurev login User2 User2Password
accurev mkws -w wkspace_name -b backing_stream -l /wkspaces/temp_location_two
accurev chws -w wkspace_name -l /wkspacees/wkspace_original_location
```

I had to go to lunch to come up with this solution. Would be nice if there was  an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the ownership of the workspace.

The simple solution is to have user1 promote the code user2 needs into a stream and have user2 create a workspace off this stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can depict a workspace as a user personal sandbox, backing a specific parent stream. Therefore, if this user1 has done significant changes on the files into his workspace, he should promote them so every other user with a workspace hanging from that stream would be updated with the changes.

[image: Initial stream and workspace]

So, if you **only** want user2 to receive all changes made by user1 on his workspace stream1_user1 (in my case, DemoDepot_juan), maybe the easiest solution would be to create a new stream (child of stream1), move user1's workspace under that stream, promote all changes and then create user2's workspace under the same stream, so it would be updated with all the changes by user1.

[image: New stream with both identical workspaces]

At this point, you could reparent user2's workspace to the inital stream, remove user1's workspace and then remove the new stream. This way, the new workspace would be identical to the old one, but the main stream will remain unmodified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just to say it, if this is still the state of the art, this limitation makes it impossible for an admin to set up workspaces for a new users, which they then own. Ugh.